# NGINX server_name configuration

Tags: nginx, ssl

I have setup my NGINX server and got the necessary ssl certificates for having a TLS/SSL connection

Am working with an API that posts data to my server. For security the API requires mutual authentication. Below is my configuration

```
server {

  ssl    on;
  listen   443;
  server_name localhost;
  ssl_certificate    /etc/ssl/server_cert.pem;
  ssl_certificate_key    /etc/ssl/mykey.key;

  ssl_verify_client on;
  ssl_verify_depth 2;
  ssl_client_certificate CA_cert.crt

  access_log /var/log/nginx/nginx.vhost.access.log;
  error_log /var/log/nginx/nginx.vhost.error.log;

  location / {
       root   /home/www/public_html/my.domain.com/public/;
       index  index.html;
  }

}
```

I did a tcpdump when testing and it seems server is rejecting traffic from the API

see screen shot of tcpdump
[image: tcpdump]

1) could this because of the `server_name` attribute being localhost?

2) should I use an IP address like `server_name 1.1.1.1:443;`  ?

Comment: What do your logs say?

Comment: IP address, yes: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html

Comment: @JennyD I have added a screenshot of the tcpdump

Comment: Not the tcpdump. The *log*.

Comment: What does `openssl s_client -connect <ip-addr>:443 -debug -msg -showcerts` show, using your IP address?